# Successfactors ODATA update entities with one to many relation

Tags: odata

im trying to use Successfactors' ODATA API to update an entity.
This entity has got a one to many relationship to another entity.
The Model looks like:
Candidate
 - custAnrede (PicklistOption (1:*)

I try to call

```
PUT <server>/odata/v2/Candidate('myId')
data: 
{"custAnrede" : {"id":"555"}}
}
```

This call fails with:

```
Inline entity are not supported for property custAnrede in non insert request.
```

When calling with data:

```
{"custAnrede": {
"__metadata": {
"uri": "PicklistOption('HRUser')"
}
}}
```

it suceeds, **but the value of custAnrede has not been changed.**

Does anybody know how a one to many relationship with ODATA can be modified ?

Thanks,
Detlef

Comment: did you succeed or is it worth looking into it? I already updated customChildObjects via Odata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar but with different objects (Parent - Child)

```
{  
   "__metadata":{  
      "uri":"cust_Overeenkomst(cust_ParentOvereenkomst_effectiveStartDate=datetime'2017-01-12T00:00:00',cust_ParentOvereenkomst_externalCode='1109',externalCode=2502L)"
   },
   "cust_event": "SO",
   "cust_eventreason":"SO-01",
   "cust_to_childsalarisgegevens":{  
      "__metadata":{  
         "uri":"cust_ChildSalarisgegevens(cust_Overeenkomst_externalCode=2502L,cust_ParentOvereenkomst_effectiveStartDate=datetime'2017-01-12T00:00:00',cust_ParentOvereenkomst_externalCode='1109',externalCode='SalComp_26')"
      },
      "cust_opmerking":"TEST Vincent",
      "cust_paycomponent":"BRUTOMAAND",
      "cust_paycompvalue":"1000"
   }
}
```

Comment: @ThomasMatecki it is a custom object